# Problema ao recuperar DataSource no Wildfly: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, wildfly, jndi

Estou tentando estabelecer uma conexão usando DataSource, e está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Feb 08, 2016 8:15:03 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
Feb 08, 2016 8:15:03 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
Feb 08, 2016 8:15:03 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
Feb 08, 2016 8:15:04 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: EJBCLIENT000017: Received server version 2 and marshalling strategies [river]
Feb 08, 2016 8:15:04 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@2a556333, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <b96b4f4>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=ingo-pc]} on channel Channel ID de71a44d (outbound) of Remoting connection 0f720e7c to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
Feb 08, 2016 8:15:04 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient <clinit>
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 2.0.1.Final
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss/datasources/trabalhoes14bim -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jboss.datasources.trabalhoes14bim
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:202)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at col.cliente.ColCliente.consultaClientePorCPF(ColCliente.java:136)
    at manager.cliente.UCCliente.cadastrarCliente(UCCliente.java:32)
    at view.teste.Main.populate(Main.java:73)
    at view.teste.Main.main(Main.java:277)
```

Não estou conseguindo resolver, recupero o `DataSource` remotamente da JNDI, conforme abaixo:

```
public static void getConnection() {

    DataSource ds = null;

    try{
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://localhost:8080");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

        properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

        Context init = new InitialContext(properties);
        Context ctx = (Context) init.lookup("java:");
        ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jboss/datasources/trabalhoes14bim");
        ctx.close();
        con = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Estou usando o server 
 - WildFly 10.0.0 Final
 - Eclipse Luna
 - MySQL 5.0.7

Comment: O erro persistiu a mesmo, mesmo mudando isso

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada, parece que é algo relacionado a eu estar usando cliente externo. O `InitialContext` sem as propriedades me retorna a exception `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException`. O Log do servidor não me diz nada além de `[org.jboss.as.naming] (default task-19) JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 21b908c3 (inbound) of Remoting connection 7be8f674 to /127.0.0.1:54170`

Comment: Log do servidor: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15002418/. 
Log do eclipse: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15002423/.
Estou tentando conectar via código em um projeto paralelo, não estou usando o Trabalho4BimES1-WebService e Trabalho4BimES1-InterfaceWeb ainda. Esse projeto paralelo do eclipse contem somente uma classe de conexão pra teste que é o código acima e um main pra invocar o metodo. Projeto: http://i.imgur.com/Fy2okOw.jpg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em poucas palavras: [não é possível fazer lookup remote de um *datasource* na JNDI em versões superiores ao JBoss AS 7](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/231013).

Irei mostrar um exemplo básico de como um cliente pode tentar recuperar um *datasource* da JNDI em versões superiores ao JBoss AS 7, demostrando alguns problemas que ocorrem e o que impossibilita de fazer isto.

Estou considerando que o seu AS já está todo configurado, então não irei tratar nada disto, apenas as fases posteriores à declaração do *datasource*.

Abaixo um exemplo comum de como costumamos declarar *datasources* no Wildfly:

```xml
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/SOPT" pool-name="poolSOPT" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.99.10:5432/stack</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>postgres</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>1000</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

Este será nossa primeira tentativa de testes (a exceção do `jndi-name`, conforme falado abaixo) e depois de iniciado o AS espera-se que o datasource seja publicado, conforme log abaixo:

```
INFO  [o.j.a.c.s.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/SOPT]
```

Como nosso teste é para recuperação remota do recurso, vamos antes fazer uma alteração, conforme observação abaixo:

> apenas recursos publicados em [`java:jboss/exported`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JNDI+Reference) são acessíveis remotamente

Dito isto, nosso `jndi-name` não será `java:jboss/datasources/SOPT`, mas sim `java:jboss/exported/datasources/SOPT`, além de retirarmos o atributo `jta`. Feito isto, com o servidor rodando, iremos agora criar uma classe cliente para recuperar o datasource. Irei configurar as propriedades diretamente no código, mas você pode criar um arquivo chamado `jndi.properties`, por padrão o [`InitialContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) recupera informações de lá.

Criei um projeto [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) básico, contendo apenas as dependências realmente necessárias para o contexto:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
    <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

No seu caso apenas a `jboss-client.jar` basta, ela traz tudo o que é necessário para recuperar recursos remotos.

Para fazer o *lookup* do recurso, usaremos este trecho de código:

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "${seu.usuario}");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "${sua.senha}");

final Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
final DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:/datasources/SOPT");
```

Agora iremos executar para o *datasource* conforme acima, abaixo o log da execução, onde obteremos erro:

```
fev 09, 2016 4:39:40 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
fev 09, 2016 4:39:40 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
fev 09, 2016 4:39:40 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
fev 09, 2016 4:39:40 PM org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver handleMessage
ERROR: org.jboss.remoting3.MessageCancelledException
fev 09, 2016 4:39:40 PM org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver handleMessage
ERROR: org.jboss.remoting3.MessageCancelledException
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:49)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:95)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$1.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:276)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:137)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.brunocesar.JNDIResource.main(JNDIResource.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$2.write(Protocol.java:138)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.WriteUtil.write(WriteUtil.java:61)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:128)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field cachedConnectionManager
    in field cm
    in object org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource@2e275207
```

Isto é devido às configurações de cache em nosso *datasource*, como o atributo `use-ccm`, etc., `CachedConnectionManagerImpl`, atributo do *wrapper* que o Wildfly usa, não é serializável, por isto uma [`NotSerializableException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) é lançada. Vamos tentar sem o atributo `use-ccm` e também sem as outras configurações que de alguma forma tem relacionamento com o *pool* de conexões, então nosso novo datasource ficará assim, apenas o essencial:

```xml
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/datasources/SOPT" pool-name="poolSOPT" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.99.10:5432/stack</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>postgres</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Depois de novo teste o erro persistirá:

```
fev 09, 2016 4:40:27 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
fev 09, 2016 4:40:27 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
fev 09, 2016 4:40:27 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
fev 09, 2016 4:40:28 PM org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver handleMessage
ERROR: org.jboss.remoting3.MessageCancelledException
fev 09, 2016 4:40:28 PM org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver handleMessage
ERROR: org.jboss.remoting3.MessageCancelledException
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:49)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:95)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$1.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:276)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:137)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.brunocesar.JNDIResource.main(JNDIResource.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$2.write(Protocol.java:138)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.WriteUtil.write(WriteUtil.java:61)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:128)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field cachedConnectionManager
    in field cm
    in object org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource@686ac2e7
```

Não há nada mais neste *datasource* que podemos retirar, `pool-name` é [obrigatório](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/schema/datasources_1_1.xsd), então apenas constatamos que, mesmo resumindo o *datasource* ao máximo ainda há objetos nele que não são serializáveis, premissa básica para que possa ser recuperado de forma remota.

Ou seja, o recurso até está publicado, podemos validar com este código:

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "${seu.usuario}");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "${sua.senha}");

final Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
final NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> namings = context.list("java:/datasources");
if (namings.hasMoreElements()) {
    final NameClassPair name = namings.next();
    System.out.println(name.getName() + " | " + name.getClassName());
}
```

Que imprimi `SOPT | org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource`, mas devido a alguns objetos não serem serializáveis não há como fazer o lookup com sucesso.

Eu não sei qual o seu contexto, o que lhe obriga a recuperar, remotamente, um *datasource* do AS. Se quer usar coisas remotas assim (é algum pré-requisito?), considere evoluir sua arquitetura, como para usar serviços, EJBs remotos, etc.

Os testes foram feitos na versão 8.1.0 do Wildfly, que era a que você havia postado originalmente. Você pode repetir o procedimento e ver se na versão 10.0.0 o comportamento ainda é o mesmo.

Alguns outros links falando sobre isto:

- https://community.jboss.org/thread/196876
- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/213902

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento, realmente muito boa, sou inexperiente quando o assunto é servidor de aplicação, comecei a aprender a usar faz pouco menos de uma semana. Um dos requisitos é fazer o uso do pool de conexões, portanto não posso tira-lo. Tem algum exemplo de como fazer isso localmente? Ou algum outro server que me permite recuperar a datasource remotamente para que eu não precise alterar boa parte do meu código. Testei no 10.0.0, o erro persistiu.

Comment: @IngoGuilhermeBothEyng você pode continuar usando um AS para isto, no entanto sua aplicação terá que rodar no AS, não fora dele. Sua aplicação rodando no AS, seja uma aplicação Web ou não, você conseguirá recupera o recurso da JNDI. Outra forma é olhar outros caras que fazem pool de conexões e você pode usá-los independente do AS, como [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) ou o [HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/). Caso a resposta tenha lhe ajudado, considere aceitá-la como a correta. Qualquer outra dúvida só abrir outras perguntas :)

Comment: Sim, eu vou fazer isso, foi mais do que satisfatória e esclarecedora sua resposta. Só mais um dúvida, um tanto quanto burra, como faço para colocar a minha aplicação para rodar no AS e não fora?

Comment: @IngoGuilhermeBothEyng existem N formas de fazer isto cara, no WF você pode ver algo aqui: [Application deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Application+deployment). As IDEs já possuem integração com os principais ASs, primeiro aconselho a você ter certeza do tipo da sua aplicação, se realmente precisa de um AS, um servlet container ou ser desktop basta, pois nem todas as aplicações são passíveis de serem implantadas em um AS. Veja o [Developer Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Developer+Guide), lá tem mais detalhes.

Comment: Outro requisito além do pool de conexões é também utilizar AS, obrigado por tudo.

Comment: @IngoGuilhermeBothEyng entendi, então você não terá problema em recuperar remotamente as conexões. Defina o empacotamento (WAR, EJB, etc.) da sua aplicação e manda bala. Qualquer coisa só falar :)

Comment: Pronto, troquei tudo para local e está tudo funcionando agora, obrigado cara, assim que eu tiver um tempo vou dar uma olhada pra aprender sobre o remoto.